# Can a Lorenz surface be a Lorentz surface?

Tags: statistics, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, riemann-surfaces, semi-riemannian-geometry

A Lorenz surface (statistics) is one possible higher dimensional extension of a Lorenz curve proposed by Taguchi, Lunetta, Arnold, Koshevoy and Mosler. [Analytic Expressions for Multivariate Lorenz Surfaces.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13171-018-00158-9)

A Lorentz surface (geometry) is a two-dimensional oriented smooth manifold with a conformal equivalence class of Lorentzian metrics. It is the analogue of a Riemann surface in indefinite signature. [Lorentz Surface.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-8rvpv4nsAhW5mXIEHd6bCKEQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLorentz_surface&usg=AOvVaw0-Hxk5d-XZRso29h0MxJKR)

> Can the two definitions coincide? Is there a known example?

I think that if we purposely define a Lorenz surface to be some analytic function and construct an extension to 3-space via revolving the function about $y=x$ then we can obtain a surface. Then it would have to be proven that this surface has a conformal equivalence class of Lorentzian metrics.